# Service Bus Connection String in Azure function is rejected

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

Im working through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-store-data-in-azure-table-storage) guide using **Azure Functions** to commit **IoTHub** messages to **Azure storage**. I'm at section 5d, where I need to create a new Service Bus Connection string for my function, but whatever I use, including the format in the guide:

```
Endpoint=<Event Hub-compatible endpoint>;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=<Primary key>
```

I get the error:

> Not a valid service bus connection string.

I’ve tried using the `Event Hub-compatible endpoint` from my IoT hub endpoints and also the `connection string –- primary key` from the access policy for iothubowner but again it rejects it.

I then created a new service bus and used that connection (see my answer below and initial optimism!) but when I tried to edit the function I get a 404 toast notification:

> Function ($DeviceDataToStorage) Error: The listener for function
>   'Functions.DeviceDataToStorage' was unable to start.
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus: The messaging entity 'Management operation
>   failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity
>   'sb://{MY SERVICE BUS CONNECTION STRING WHICH WAS
>   ACCEPTED}/{EVENTHUBNAME}' could not be found..' could not be found.

Can anyone who has used Azure functions before advise what format this needs to be in or more importantly where exactly in the portal I can get this from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I checked this issue. As [Prepare for IoT Hub connection to read messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-store-data-in-azure-table-storage#prepare-for-iot-hub-connection-to-read-messages) states that you need to construct the connection string for your IoT hub endpoint as follows:

`Endpoint={Event Hub-compatible endpoint};SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey={Primary key}`

Replace **{Event Hub-compatible endpoint}** with:

[image]

Replace **{Primary key}** with:

[image]

> Not a valid service bus connection string.

I assumed that you encounter this error when you creating a new **Event Hub connection** as follows:

[image]

When you add new connection string for your Event Hub, it should look like as follows:

[image]

**Note:** I assumed that you have confused with Service Bus connection string and IoT Hub connection string.

Connection string for Service Bus:

`Endpoint=sb://{your-servicebus-name}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={SharedAccessKeyName};SharedAccessKey={SharedAccessKey}`

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Not sure what or how it worked this time, but put the same connection string in as before and it seems happy with the format. Maybe I had a trailing semi-colon?

Comment: I have tested by adding trailing semi-colon or blank in the end, it could work, while semi-colon or blank in the beginning of your connection string could not be validated.

Answer (score 3):

Thought I figured it out, but I hadn't.
Here's what I thought worked, but it didn't

*

> Its missing from the tutorial, but you need to manually create a new
>   service bus endpoint (see
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues)
>   and copy the `CONNECTIONSTRING-PRIMARYKEY` from the
>   `RootManageSharedAccessKey` policy of `Shared Access Policies`.

*

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't actually work. While it accepted the connection string as valid, it gives a 404 as its appending the IotHub name field on the connection string (which kinda makes sense), so still not sure how to assemble the connection string?